# Spam users requesting profile page creating errors that fill event log

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have had a site that fell prey to the spam user registrations that was found in the summer.  I have stopped the registration but now I am getting these users requestion their profile pages and as a result there are errors being logged in the event viewer.  These events are clogging the event viewer in 24 hrs to the point where it affects site performance and the event viewer can not load.

the following is one of the errors that gets logged.

### ERROR:

**UserName**:

**ActiveTabID**:61

**ActiveTabName**:My Profile

**RawURL**:/Activity-Feed/My-Profile/userId/285

**AbsoluteURL**:/Default.aspx

**AbsoluteURLReferrer**:http://www.aSitePortal.com/

**UserAgent**:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36

**DefaultDataProvider**:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

**ExceptionGUID**:6eff0116-bc77-4394-849b-0f5b67ba040f

**InnerException**:Not Found

**FileName**:

**FileLineNumber**:0

**FileColumnNumber**:0

**Method**:DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Users.ViewProfile.OnInit

**StackTrace**:

**Message**:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Not Found
   at DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Users.ViewProfile.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
   at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child)
   at DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.InjectModuleContent(Control content)
   at DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at DotNetNuke.UI.Containers.Container.get_ModuleControl()
   at DotNetNuke.UI.Containers.Container.ProcessModule()
   at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Pane.InjectModule(ModuleInfo module)
```

**Source**:

**Server Name**: RD00155D50E2D9

This happens right after a search index scheduled event throws an error.  So it might be related.

**NOTE:**  this site suffered from the robot spam user registrations.  But since then this site has been moved to a new server and instance of DNN and the user registration is set to **none** right now.

### QUESTION:

How can I reject these requests specifically for one portal (as only one portal is affected) and stop them being logged?

Thanks in advance.

Jordan

### EDIT 1:

so this outlines the spam user issue:  http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/154984/spammer-registrations#Comment634

### EDIT 2

I have set the permission of the activity and profile page to admin only,  this has not removed the erros

### EDIT 3:

I also tried to disable and rename the My Profile page and that did not remove the errors either.

Comment: if you vote down its nice to have a reason as to why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a workaround which is based on the solution found [in this DNN wiki page](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/replacing-registration-page-with-custom-and-blocking-the-default-register-page)

In the end I needed to set up a request filter.  This problem only affected one of the portals in my installation so I could set up a request filter regex with that specific domain and the profile pages the spam users were trying to access.

The following is a picture of the request filters I set up, they are not portal specific , you would have to change the regex for yourself.

I hope this can help someone else

[image]